# Python Iterate over Folders and combine csv files inside

Tags: python, csv

Windows OS - I've got several hundred subdirectories and each subdirectory contains 1 or more .csv files.  All the files are identical in structure.  I'm trying to loop through each folder and concat all the files in each subdirectory into a new file combining all the .csv files in that subdirectory.

example:

folder1 -> file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv -->> file1.csv, file2.csv, file3.csv, combined.csv

folder2 -> file1.csv, file2.csv -->> file1.csv, file2.csv, combined.csv

Very new to coding and getting lost in this.  Tried using os.walk but completely failed.

Comment: it's late .. but just have a look at : https://pymotw.com/2/glob/

Comment: [Similar Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17586573/python-combing-data-from-different-csv-files-into-one)

Answer (score 0):

The generator produced by `os.walk` yields three items each iteration: the path of the current directory in the walk, a list of paths representing sub directories that will be traversed next, and a list of filenames contained in the current directory.

If for whatever reason you don't want to walk certain file paths, you should remove entries from what I called `sub` below (the list of sub directories contained in `root`). This will prevent `os.walk` from traversing any paths you removed.

My code does not prune the walk. Be sure to update this if you don't want to traverse an entire file subtree.

The following outline should work for this although I haven't been able to test this on Windows. I have no reason to think it'll behave differently.

```
import os
import sys


def write_files(sources, combined):
    # Want the first header
    with open(sources[0], 'r') as first:
        combined.write(first.read())

    for i in range(1, len(sources)):
        with open(sources[i], 'r') as s:
            # Ignore the rest of the headers
            next(s, None)
            for line in s:
                combined.write(line)


def concatenate_csvs(root_path):
    for root, sub, files in os.walk(root_path):
        filenames = [os.path.join(root, filename) for filename in files
                     if filename.endswith('.csv')]
        combined_path = os.path.join(root, 'combined.csv')
        with open(combined_path, 'w+') as combined:
            write_files(filenames, combined)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = sys.argv[1]
    concatenate_csvs(path)
```

Comment: What command line argument is passed?  I tried passing the absolute path to the root directory, the script executes without error, but no files are created or modified.

Comment: @user2221205 Are you running `python myscript.py C:\absolute\path\to\directory`? This generates combined files for me.

Comment: Yes. running python 3.4.4 if that makes a difference.

Comment: @user2221205 I just tested this on Windows with Python 3.6 and this works. Did you directly copy and paste the code? I would include prints along the way to make sure things are actually happening.

Comment: Yes.  I'm thinking it's an issue with the way the folders are named.  The naming convention used is Location Name (State-Month), i.e. "San Antonio (TX-01)" and "San Antonio (TX-02)".